# Is my proof correct? Cantor set property.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

I self-study topology via Viro's Elementary Topology Textbook. I've got a problem there to proof that Cantor set doesn't intersect $(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})$, I've proven it, but I haven't found any solution in textbook, so I'd like to know whether my proof is correct. So here it is:
Let $K$ be Cantor Set:
$$ K = \{x\in \mathbb{R}|x = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_k}{3^k}\} $$
Where $a_k \in \{0,2\}$. Suppose that $\exists x \in K : x \in (\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})$, then:
$$ \frac{1}{3} <\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_k}{3^k} < \frac{2}{3} $$

Let's multiply by $3$:
$$ 1 <\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_k}{3^{k-1}} < 2 $$
We have, that $ 1 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{3^k} $, then:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{3^k} <\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_k}{3^{k-1}} < 2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{3^k} $$
Let's substract $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{3^k}$:
$$ 0 <\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{3a_k-2}{3^k} < \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{3^k} $$
Let's name $3a_k-2$ as $b_k$. Notice, that $b_k \in \{-2,4\}$, then we have:
$$ 0 <\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{b_k}{3^k} < \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{3^k} $$
Let's divide by $2$:
$$0 <\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{b_k}{2}}{3^k} < \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^k}$$
Let's return to $a_k$:
$$0 <\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{3a_k}{2} - 1}{3^k} < \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^k}$$
Then:
$$ \frac{3a_k}{2} - 1 < 1 $$
Which equals to:
$$\frac{3a_k}{2} < 0$$
Contradiction. Then Cantor set doesn't intersect $(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})$.

Comment: This is awfully complicated, and it makes me wonder what definition of $K$ you are using. Using [the most common definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Construction_and_formula_of_the_ternary_set), there is a half line proof: $K = \cap_{n=1}^\infty C_n$ where $C_2 = [0,\frac{1}{3}] \cup [\frac{2}{3},1]$, hence $K \subset C_2$.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^k} = 0$ ? This is not true

Comment: I added $K$ set definition which is given by Viro's textbook.

Comment: Oh, yeah, indeed, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^k} \neq 0 $, my bad.

Comment: Okay, not I've got rid of this mistake. Can you say whether my proof correct now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems complicated:

Notice instead:

If $\frac 13 < x < \frac 23$

For any  $k= \sum\limits_{k=1; }^{\infty}\frac {a_k}{3^k}\in K$ we know $k=\sum\limits_{k=1; }^{\infty}\frac {a_k}{3^k} \ge \frac {a_1}3$ and if $a_1 = 2$ then $k > x$

We also know that $k = \sum\limits_{k=1; }^{\infty}\frac {a_k}{3^k} \le \frac {a_1}3 + \sum\limits_{k=2; }^{\infty}\frac 2{3^k}$.  So if $a_1 =0$ then $k < 0 + \sum\limits_{k=2; }^{\infty}\frac 2{3^k} = \frac 13<x$.

$x \ne k$ for any $k \in K$.

.....

However more to the point:

Assuming you have actually verified that every  real number in $[0, 1]$ has a base three decimal extension and that with the exception of trailing $2$s and trailing $0$s these are unique;

Then it is apperant that if $\frac 13 < x < \frac 23$ then $x = \frac 13+y$ for some $0 < y < \frac 13$.

Thus the decimal expansion of $x$ must have $1$ as its first digit.

====

But so far as I can tell your proof is correct but it was just too long to read.  It was pretty clear your concepts were sound and thinking was good and it would work but... I didn't want to read the details.

Answer (score 2):

In one definition of the Cantor set, you simply remove the middle third of all remaining intervals iteratively,  in the unit interval.

Thus, $(\dfrac 13,\dfrac 23)$ is, in fact, the first interval taken out.

Alternatively,  if you define the Cantor set as the set of numbers in the unit interval whose ternary representation has no $1$'s, this is also clear, since any point in $(\dfrac 13,\dfrac 23)$ has ternary representation of the form $0.1\dots$.